# SOQL to get primary contact ID for Account in NPSP

Tags: soql, account, contact, npsp

I want to get the name of the contact in the lookup field `npe01__One2OneContact__c` on Account object.

How do I get the contact name using a SOQL query?

Comment: Since its relationship field shouldn't it be npe01__One2OneContact__r.Name? Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing NPSP-specific about querying from the Household to the Primary Contact as such - it's just a normal [SOQL relationship query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm), using the

```
Lookup_Field__r.Child_Field__c
```

syntax, which here would be

```
npe01__One2OneContact__r.Name
```

The only unique feature of the NPSP that comes into play here is the account model. Because you're working in an org that *has* Primary Contacts, you should be using [NPSP 3.0+ with the Household Account model](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Primary-Contact), which is where that feature is available.